# db.savechanges() line freezes in EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, oracle11g

When the line db.savechanges() hits the breakpoint. Nothing happens. no errors in the catch block. The browser just freezes and data is not saved. I am using oracle with asp.net mvc. my code is given below;

```
public ResponseResult AddUserPermission(USER_PERMISSION permission)
{
    try
    {

        _db.Entry(permission).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return new ResponseResult();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //return new ResponseResult();
        return new ResponseResult(ResutlType.Error, ex.Message);
    }


}
```

And the controller calls the method is given below:

```
[HttpPost]
[CustomAuthorize("Admin")]
public ActionResult Create(USER model)
{
    try
    {

        string moduleId = Request.Form["ModuleId"];
        string isSelected = Request.Form["IsSelected"];

        model.DATE_CREATED = DateTime.Now;
        model.DATE_UPDATED = DateTime.Now;
        model.STATUS = (int)Status.Active;

        var userPermission = processPermissionData(moduleId, isSelected);
        //userPermission contains a list of permissions which i am trying to save
        _userService.Add(model);

        foreach (var permission in userPermission)
        {
            _userService.AddUserPermission(permission);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I get no response from the browser or VS 15. All i get is the loading sign in the browser tab.

Comment: How long did you leave it in the frozen state? There's not enough info in here to answer the question anyway.

Comment: i left it for 10 mins. what else do u want to know? i have cleared my cache before running this. 
_userService.Add(model);
This line works perfectly but the latter "_userService.AddUserPermission(permission);" does not work

Comment: Well the code you show is plain old EF stuff, nothing to suggest any reason why it would freeze.

Comment: can you place a trace on the DB...does it even attempt to hit the Db.

Comment: NO, it does not hit db @bilpor

Comment: Did you modify the `DbContext` command timeout, either via `web.config` connection string or programmatically in your `DbContext` constructor or somewhere else?

Comment: In this situation, I would create a new temp project. Ensure you have the power tools installed via nugget, then I'd reverse engineer the Oracle DB into my temp project. Compare the objects and connection strings against your application and see what differences you have.